# Mouse hover in pie chart windows form c#

Tags: c#, winforms, pie-chart

How can I show the quantity in my pie chart, when I hover the cursor over the pie chart, I have this code but it doesn't work. I'm new in this c# code

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            conexion.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select\r\ncount([referral_id]) as 'Count',\r\n[referral_type] as 'Type'\r\n\r\nfrom AlteryxDB.dbo.t_prd_pbixpipeline_crt2023\r\n\r\nwhere [ref_status]='Pending' and \r\n([recipient_eid] ='22216' and [referral_eid]='22216')\r\n\r\ngroup by\r\n[referral_type]", conexion);
            da.Fill(dt);
            chart3.DataSource = dt;
            conexion.Close();

            chart3.Series["Count"].XValueMember = "Type";
            chart3.Series["Count"].YValueMembers = "Count";
```

I try put

`chart3.Series["Count"].labeltooltip = "Count"`

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in the property name. The correct property for setting the `tooltip` is `ToolTip`. Also you might also need the `ToolTip` for displaying.

The updated version of your code -

```cs
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
conexion.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT COUNT([referral_id]) as 'Count', [referral_type] as 'Type' FROM AlteryxDB.dbo.t_prd_pbixpipeline_crt2023 WHERE [ref_status]='Pending' AND ([recipient_eid] ='22216' AND [referral_eid]='22216') GROUP BY [referral_type]", conexion);
da.Fill(dt);
conexion.Close();

chart3.DataSource = dt;
chart3.Series["Count"].XValueMember = "Type";
chart3.Series["Count"].YValueMembers = "Count";

chart3.Series["Count"].ToolTip = "#VALX: #VALY";
```

For reference: [ToolTip Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tooltip?view=windowsdesktop-8.0)